# React: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this simple code:

```
    class App extends Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <PanelPayment />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default App
```

And this:

```
export default class PanelPayment {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>Pay now!</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And I am getting error:

> **TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function**

```
class.App.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
at _classCallCheck (class.App.js:66)
at PanelPayment (class.PanelPayment.js:3)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:305
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:304)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:279)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:187)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:522)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
at mountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:104)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:126)
at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
at Object._renderNewRootComponent (ReactMount.js:319)
at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (ReactMount.js:401)
at Object.render (ReactMount.js:422)
at Object../src/index.js (index.js:15)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap de5a69c98061cf2fbc7c:669)
at fn (bootstrap de5a69c98061cf2fbc7c:87)
at Object.0 (registerServiceWorker.js:108)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap de5a69c98061cf2fbc7c:669)
at bootstrap de5a69c98061cf2fbc7c:715
at bundle.js:719
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget extend it as React.Component class:

```
export default class PanelPayment extends Component{
 render() {
     return (
         <div>
             <button>Pay now!</button>
         </div>
     )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare PanelPayment as a react component.

```js
class PanelPayment extends Component{
 render() {
     return (
         <div>
             <button>Pay now!</button>
         </div>
     )
 }
}
export default PanelPayment
```

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly each React class must inherit from `Component` class. Currently your `PanelPayment` class is not!
- Secondly in a single `js` file, there can be only 1 default class. In case you have both the classes in single file then you can export only one of them as default.